# How to get a list of valid column data types in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

```sql
select typname
from pg_type
```

Will return a list of data types. Some of them can be used when creating a table (numeric) while others can't be used (cardinal_number). How get a list of valid column data types?

Comment: A good place to start: the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT typname
FROM pg_type
WHERE typtype NOT IN ('p', 'd');
```

From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/catalog-pg-type.html):

> typtype is b for a base type, c for a composite type (e.g., a table's row type), d for a domain, e for an enum type, or p for a pseudo-type. See also typrelid and typbasetype